# Не получается найти текстовое поле при прохождении теста selenide для ввода логина mail.ru

Tags: java, test-automation, selenide

Как я понял это связано с тем, что окно входа динамически генерируется, поэтому обычное копирование xpath не поможет. Я никак не могу решить эту проблему. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: Это даже у автозаполнения хрома не получается. Рекомендую через компьютерное зрение.

Comment: @eri не могли бы подробнее объяснить о компьютерном зрение, это есть в selenide?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, поле для ввода просто находится внутри iframe. Сначала надо в него переключиться.

Что-то вроде

```
open("https://mail.ru/");
$(".ph-login").shouldHave(text("Войти")).click();
Selenide.switchTo().frame(14);
$(".login-panel [name=username]").val("andrei").pressEnter();
```